# Any non-zero solution of some second-order differential equation is not $2\pi$-period

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Suppose $$\frac {{d^2}y}{dx^2}+P(x)y = 0$$ where $P(x)$ is continuous and satisfying $n^2<P(x)<(n+1)^2$ where $n$ is a non-negative integer. Prove that any non-zero solution of the above second-order differential equation is not $2\pi$-periodic.

There are two facts I know that may be useful to the proof:

1. $y''+Q(x)y=0$ where $Q(x)$ is continuous on $[a,+\infty]$ and satisfying $Q(x)\geq m>0$, then the distance between any two immediate zeros of non-zero solution of it is less than $\frac {\pi}{\sqrt{m}}$.
2. $y''+Q(x)y=0$ where $Q(x)$ is continuous on $[a,+\infty]$ and satisfying $Q(x)\leq M \ (M>0)$, then the distance between any two immediate zeros of non-zero solution of it is larger than $\frac {\pi}{\sqrt{M}}$.

From this, I can't get a contradiction since if there is such a solution, with $x_0$ and $x_0+2\pi$ two zeros, then there can be $2n$ zeros between them with each of adjacent distance $d_j$ satisfying $\frac {\pi}{n+1}< d_j < \frac {\pi}{n}$. Does anyone know how to prove the result? Thank you

Comment: What would your analysis be if $P(x)$ were a constant function within these bounds? Could then $2\pi$ be a period of the solution?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think here $P(x)$ is considered as a non-constant function by default

Comment: You can treat the general case very close to the constant case.

Comment: @LutzLehmann If it's the constant case,then the solution is irrational multiple of $\pi$,so it's still not $2\pi$-periodic I think

Comment: No, that is not the correct claim, you can also get rational multiples of $\pi$. You need to use the inequality to exclude $2$ from these rational multipliers.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes,I made a mistake.So generally,we can approximate it with simple function,hence the solution is something like $\sum \chi_{E_k}cos(a_k x)$.am I right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there. If a solution were periodic, it would have, in every period starting (and thus ending) at a root, an even number of segments between roots, an equal number of positive and negative-valued segments.

So if it were $2n$ segments or less, the upper bound gives a total length strictly smaller than $2$. For $2n+2$ segments or more, the lower bound gives a total length strictly larger than $2\pi$. In no way is it possible to get the total length equal to $2\pi$.

Comment: Why it must have even segment

Comment: Because for second-order DE, by uniqueness, all roots of non-trivial solutions are simple, so the function switches sign. Now add the assumption of a periodic solution having not only the same sign but the same value repeated after a period,...