# How to prove that the solution of this ordinary differential equation is not 2π-periodic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential

Here is the questions：
$$\frac{\mathrm{d^2x} }{\mathrm{d} t^2}+p(t)x=0$$
and $$ n^2<p(t)<(n+1)^2,$$
where $p(t)$ is a continuous function of $t$，and $n$ is an integer.

How to prove that the solution of this ordinary differential equation is not $2\pi$-periodic?
Here are some of my thoughts:

- According to the Sturm comparison theorem，if $p(t)>m>0$ and $x=\varphi (t)$ is a solution of the ODE,then we can get that for any two adjacent roots of $x(t)$ the distance between them is less than $\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{m}}$, because we can use $x''+mx=0$ to compare to this ODE.
- The same if $p(t)<m$ and $x=\varphi (t)$ is a solution of the ODE, then we can get that for any two adjacent roots of $x(t)$, the distance between them is larger than $\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{m}}$, because we can use $x''+mx=0$ compare to this ode.

I would be grateful if you could help me

Comment: Almost identical question with the same spelling errors: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247397/any-non-zero-solution-of-some-second-order-differential-equation-is-not-2-pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you shift the origin to the first root $x_0$, show that $$x_{2n}<2\pi<x_{2n+2}.$$ Note that for a periodic function, you would also need that not only the values, but also the derivatives repeat. However the odd-numbered roots have an opposite sign to $x_0$ in the derivatives.

You already enumerated all the necessary facts.